# How to read some specific columns in a file?

Tags: ada

I have the first few lines of a text file `fx.txt` with the following contents:

```
t(ms) ForceX(N)  ForceY(N)
 0.0     10.0      20.0
 1.0     15.0      10.9
 2.0     12.0      30.0
```

I would like to read say the contents of the `first column` and of the `third column`. How to go about in Ada?

**Update**

Here's my updated code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.IO_Exceptions;


procedure Get_Projections is

   Input_File                : File_Type;
   Value                     : Long_Float;


   procedure Open_Data_Read (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
                             Name    : in String;
                             Success : out Boolean) is separate;
   Success                   : Boolean;


begin

   Open_Data_Read (File => Input_File, Name => "fx.txt", Success => Success);
       if not Success then
          return;
       end if;

   Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line(File => Input_File, Spacing => 1);

   while not End_Of_File (Input_File) loop

     begin
       Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (File => Input_File, Item => Value);
       exception
          when ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR =>
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (" Data error");
     end;
     Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Value, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);

     begin
       Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (File => Input_File, Item => Value);
       exception
          when ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR =>
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (" Data error");
     end;
     Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Value, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);

     begin
       Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Get (File => Input_File, Item => Value);
       exception
          when ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR =>
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (" Data error");
     end;
     Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Value, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);


   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.Close (File => Input_File);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Item => "Reading file success: " & Boolean'Image (Success));


end Get_Projections;
```

and the `separate` `Open_Data_Read.adb`:

```
separate (get_projections)

procedure Open_Data_Read (File : in out  Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;
                 Name : in String; Success : out Boolean) is

   --this procedure prepares a file for reading
     begin
      Success := True;
      begin
         Ada.Text_IO.Open
           (File => File,
            Mode => Ada.Text_IO.In_File,
            Name => Name);
      exception
         when Ada.Text_IO.Name_Error  =>
         Success := False;
         Ada.Text_IO.Put (File => Standard_Error, Item => "****File not found....****");
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Item => "Reading file success: " & Boolean'Image (Success));
  end;
end Open_Data_Read;
```

**Exceptions data_error are not caught**. What is wrong?

*Note the above is just a crude piece of code. I can decide not to store the values in the second column later on*

Comment: @Keith Thompson I can read a file with a single column. I can use `Skip_Line` to ignore the header. I do not know how to use the `Set_col` procedure if I believe this is the right way to ask to go to a column number. Then I do not know how to use `Set_Col` and still make two columns to be read. Should I being juggling with the `Set_Col` from column `1` to `3` for each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`procedure Get`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-9.html) "skips any leading blanks, line terminators, or page terminators." Once you skip the header, just keep reading until `End_Of_File` is true. Call `Get` in groups of three and discard the middle value.

Addendum: Much of the detail depends on the goal. This [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is a minimal attempt to acquire columns one and three, while reporting malformed numbers. The alternative is to read  everything as a `String` and use the corresponding version of `Get`.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Get_Data is

   package TIO renames Ada.Text_IO;
   package FIO renames Ada.Float_Text_IO;

   Data  : TIO.File_Type;
   Value : Float;

begin
   TIO.Open (Data, TIO.In_File, "data.txt");
   TIO.Skip_Line (Data);
   while not TIO.End_Of_File (Data) loop
        FIO.Get (Data, Value);
        FIO.Put (Value, 3, 5, 0); TIO.Put (" ");
        FIO.Get (Data, Value); -- Discard
        FIO.Get (Data, Value);
        FIO.Put (Value, 3, 5, 0); TIO.New_Line;
   end loop;
   exception
      when TIO.End_Error => null;
      when TIO.Data_Error =>
         TIO.Put_Line ("Data error: " & TIO.Name (Data));
end Get_Data;
```

Comment: One really should instantiate `Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO` with the desired floating point type, but `Ada.Float_Text_IO` or `Ada.Long_Float_Text_IO` are a convenient alternative.

Comment: This works. But where to put the line `Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line(1)`? I cannot certainly put it in the `while not End_Of_File (Input_File)` loop. 1 vote up.

Comment: Call `Skip_Line` before the loop starts. I typically check `End_of_File` after each group, of three in this case. Don't forget to  catch `Data_Error`. I'd urge you to leave this open a bit; my usage is a little stereotypical, and there may be a better way.

Comment: @ trashgod I have now modified the code to put the `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR` is separate `Get` blocks. Is it ok now?

Comment: @ trashgod The `ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.DATA_ERROR` is not working when I have say a character instead of a number in a column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Nothing jumps out at me. Is the goal on malformed input to report & continue, or to halt?

Comment: @ trashgod To inform by the message `Data Error`. I guess then the program would also halt....not sure about this though!

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Premature `End_of_File` or spurious empty line(s) can also be a problem. I'm afraid I don't have a general solution. I _can_ verify that `Data Error` arises for non-numeric data.