# Get_line in Ada

Tags: ada

I have a little problem in using get_line  to be more concret I must take a line from a file and use it. I don't know how especially if the lines aren't constitute just from characters there's also float can I use get_line in this case?
Thank you. Let's start with this little example:

```
with Ada.Text_Io;

use Ada.Text_Io;

procedure Getline is

   A:String;

   T:string;

begin

   Open(File => F, Mode => In_File, Name => Nom_Fichier);

   A:=Get_Line(F,In_File, T);

   Put(A);

end Getline;`
```

Comment: You might look at the approaches examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9876568/230513).

Comment: Can you expand on how you have to "use it"?

Comment: I think you need to clarify (for yourself) what you're trying to do.  If you're using `Ada.Text_IO`, then everything in the file *is* a character.  If the file contains the five characters "1.234", they're still five characters, and your job is to take those characters and parse them to produce a float.  (Ada has several ways to help you do this.)  If the file contains the same 4 or 8 bytes that would be used to store a float in memory, then it's not a text file and you should be using a different I/O package.  But you do need to be clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank's for your quick answers you're rignt it's a .stl file I don't know what parameters i must use for get_line i have some data and i want to take the floats there and to make them in a table .

Comment: No one knows how to use get_line?

Comment: @user2539972 trashgod gave you a link, have you tried looking there?

Comment: It looks like `.stl` can be ASCII or binary; which are you using?

Comment: We know how to use Get_Line, but we don't know what you're trying to do. At the very least give us an example of the line you are trying to read, and what you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're just guessing the parameters you should pass to `Get_Line`. I suggest you have a look at the relevant part in the [ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-7.html): The *function* `Get_Line` only takes a `File_Type` and returns a `String`; the *procedure* `Get_Line` takes a `File_Type` and, as output parameters, a `String` and a `Natural`.

Then, `String` is an [indefinite subtype](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Indefinite_subtype), meaning that you *have* to assign something to `A` at declaration, or provide boundaries for it. Here's a working version of your example code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Getline is
   F : File_Type;
   File_Path : constant String := "testfile.stl";
begin
   Open (File => F, Mode => In_File, Name => File_Path);
   declare
      A : String := Get_Line (F);
   begin
      Put (A);
   end;
   Close (File => F);
end Getline;
```

Before you try something more complex, you should get familiar with the basics of the language. The [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming) is a good place to start. If you want to get your actual question about reading floats from the line answered, you need to provide more details about how a potential line looks like.

Comment: Thank's for your answer and advices.

Answer (score 1):

`Get_Line` simply interprets the "line" (set of characters up to the next line terminator or end of file) as text, and gives it to the caller that way. Thus if the file contains:

```
10.52
```

Then your call to `Get_Line` will return the string "10.52".

It may be true that if you tried to read that using `Float_Text_IO` you would get the float value `10.52` back. However, there's no metadata associated with text in text files, so the computer has no way of knowing that text happens to be a representable float without parsing it and seeing if it can make a float out of it. It of course isn't going to bother to do that unless you ask it to via something like a call into `Float_Text_IO`